# Rendering Markup from JS array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is the original Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/404h0u20/

I am trying to use the JS to render the HTML to obey the principle of DRY. Here:

https://jsfiddle.net/404h0u20/2/

The relevant code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(bars).append("<ol>")
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        $(bars).append("<li><a>" + String(amenities[i][0]) + "</a></li>");
    }
    $(bars).append("</ol>")

    $(shopping).append("<ol>")
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $(shopping).append("<li><a>" + String(amenities[i][0]) + "</a></li>");
    }
    $(shopping).append("</ol>")

    $(restaurants).append("<ol>")
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $(restaurants).append("<li><a>" + String(amenities[i][0]) + "</a></li>");
    }
    $(restaurants).append("</ol>")

    $(placesOfInterest).append("<ol>")
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        $(placesOfInterest).append("<li><a>" + String(amenities[i][0]) + "</a></li>");
    }
    $(placesOfInterest).append("</ol>")
});
```

But it doesn't create an ordered list, and it creates the wrong data from the second tab onwards?!

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try some DRY with `each()` and attribute selector

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
           $('.lists').append('<ol>')
           $.each(amenities,function(i,v){
           $('[data-amenity='+v[4]+']').next().find('ol').append("<li><a>" + String(v[0]) + "</a></li>");
           });
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vobefn04/1/

Comment: This one doesn't display like the original one with written HTML?

Comment: is that a question?, if it is,yes it displays like the original

Comment: Sorry didn't make myself clear! In the original, clicking a list item makes the info box appear exactly the same as clicking the map marker itself. But this functionality has been lost?

This code is basically the Sahara though, so thanks for that

Comment: you may want to change the color of the number on the map because i didn't see them and i bet a lot of people wan't see them